# Creating A Sign Up Activity using Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my application I am creating a sign up activity using parse database and I used the `signUpInBackground()` but when I run the code on the emulator the parse is giving me a message that says "unauthorised.

```
Join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            dialog.setMessage("Please Wait While Signing Up");
            dialog.show();

            final ParseUser user =new ParseUser();

            user.setUsername(Username.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setPassword(Password.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setEmail(Email.getText().toString().trim());
            user.put("firstName", FirstName.getText().toString().trim());
            user.put("lastName", LastName.getText().toString().trim());

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if(e!=null){
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SignUp.this,LogIn.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you really want to use Parse? Parse service will end in january 2017.

Comment: I'm working on an application for the university. I will host it on parse to show it to my instructor. I should deliver next week.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code. Do you have Parse initalized correctly?

Comment: Yes thee problem was with parse, it wasn't initialized right...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialise Parse in your `Application` class, are you setting your `ACL`?

Also are your keys correct when you initialise?

Make sure you follow the [Quick Start Guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new).